# x86_64-linux-gnu/libm.so: undefined reference to `__strtof128_nan@GLIBC_PRIVATE'

Tags: hyperlink, compilation, lib

When I compile the codes, there is error:
/usr/lib/gcc/x86_64-linux-gnu/4.8/../../../x86_64-linux-gnu/libm.so: undefined reference to `__strtof128_nan@GLIBC_PRIVATE'

I know the libm and libc versions may don't use the same version of gblic, and review my lib versions.

1、__strtof128_nan@GLIBC_PRIVATE is an internal reference in the libm library of glibc, used to call into the libc library. These internal references only work properly if libm and libc were part of the same glibc build.
2、the lib version is:
shy@ubuntu-txj:~$ /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/lib
libc-2.19.so        libc-2.27.so        libc.so.6           libm-2.27.so        libm.so.6           libpthread-2.19.so  libpthread.so.0

so how can I solve the problem?